# Mail loop between spam filter and 365

Tags: exchange, spam, microsoft-office-365

I was wondering if anyone has seen this before.  We have our own spam filter cluster that emails go through before being sent on to 365.  When emailing from our company domain (365 hosted) to another 365 hosted customer domain we receive an NDR from our spam filter stating that:

Remote Server returned '554 5.4.0 Error: too many hops'

These are two completely separate 365 tenancies, both have the same mail flow of going out of 365, to our spam filter back to 365.  My customer emails don't get this too many hops error but I do when emailing them?

Looking at the header analysis I can see the Outlook host sending the message straight back to our spam filter cluster, step 8 - 9, which the spam filter tries to send it back to 365 again, getting stuck in a loop until the too many hops count has been reached.

[Header breakdown showing communications between our spam filter server and 365](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe7QM.jpg)

Completely stumped and Microsoft support has thus far not helped.

Kind regards,
Tim

Comment: My recommendation would be to discuss with the spam filter company.  I would also be really concerned that it "sat" at the spam filter service for over 20 minutes.

Comment: Spent quite a bit of time speaking to SpamTitan regarding this and they have pushed me back to Microsoft each time.  In the spam filter logging we can see the message gets an ID from Microsoft servers.

SMTP Response: 250 2.6.0 [InternalId=8723078586245, Hostname=CWXP123MB5132.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 45515 bytes in 0.095, 466.597 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery

But when we do a message trace from EAC we can't see this message.  

SpamTitan thinks that Microsoft are doing an MX lookup then sending it straight back to our spam filter.

Comment: Which info did you use for header analysis? The NDR/DSN(bounce) message's header or the original message header?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I used the original message header that is included in plain text on the email rather than NDRs header itself.

Comment: Did the recipient/sender side configure any inbox/transport rules? According to the hop 6, there seems to be a delay, do you see any entries about this process in the log of the spam filter?

Comment: Hi Ivan, no inbox or transport rules on either side on either mailbox.  My side doesn't even have a connector to simplify the setup.  Other side has a connector to only allow email to be delivered from our spam filter server.

Note the side with a connector in place is the side sending so the receiving connector doesn't even play a part in this issue.

Comment: Sorry for that I'm not familiar with this spam filter, however, maybe you could bypass it and send emails directly? Then see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thats okay Ivan, its our own inhouse spam filter cluster.  I have proven today that its not the spam filter because I am able to send emails between myself and customer that I originally found this issue on, both my domain and customers domain use said spam filter and emails flow fine both ways.  Its only our works 365 tenancy that appears to experience this issue so it has to be a setting there.  If I find out what it is I will let you know.

Comment: @TimEarl have you figured out a resolution for this problem?